# How to show motorola lock screen media controls

Tags: android, android-notifications, motorola, android-mediasession

My app has a notification while media is playing on a remote device that my app controls. On most devices the notification (not using the `MediaStyle` notification) shows up fine on the lock screen but I guess on Motorola phones it doesn't. My users say most media apps show some controls on the screen but not their notification.

How can I make sure my app shows those controls? I don't have a motorola phone to test.

I am already creating `MediaSessionCompat` and for example on Android Wear I can see my controls just fine without any extra code.

Edit: Adding some of the code.

MediaSession:

```
mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(MediaNotificationService.this, TAG);
mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSessionCallback());
mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
metadataBuilder.putString(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, mediaTitle);
metadataBuilder.putBitmap(MediaMetadata.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM_ART, image);
mediaSession.setMetadata(metadataBuilder.build());
setMediaSessionState(playStateStatus);
mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

And the notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_notification_icon)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setContentIntent(someActivityIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW);
RemoteViews smallNotificationViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.playing_notification);
RemoteViews bigNotificationViews = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(),R.layout.playing_notification_big);
if (OSUtils.lollipopOrHigher) {
    mBuilder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
}
//set a bunch of pending intents for buttons inside the layouts
... //code to create notification channel if it doesn't exist
notification = mBuilder.build();
notification.contentView = smallNotificationViews;
if (OSUtils.isJellyBeanOrAbove) {
    notification.bigContentView = bigNotificationViews;
}
notify(notification);
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: How do you create the notification? Please add some code.

Comment: Added the code. Like I said, it isn't a media style notification. But I am creating a `MediaSession` and the media controls work just fine on Android Wear. They also work fine on a Motorola phone with KitKat.